# How to find value within array of struct in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I have an array of struct which contains different elements (struct)

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date1: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- primaryKey: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date2: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Sample data

```
+----------+-------------------+------+ 
| id| date1|values| 
+----------+-------------------+------+ 
|102|2025-05-11 20:00:00| 10| 
|102|2022-07-05 20:00:00| 12| 
+----------+-------------------+------+
```

I am trying to come up with a sql query for the following condition:
if table.data.values.primaryKey = "12" --- then check table.data.date1 to see if it is not > current_date()

Also, table.data.values.primaryKey should be equal to "10" and table.date.date1 for when values=10 should be > current(date)

I am unsure how to do this in sql.  Would appreciate any input here.

so far, this is the where clause I came up with:

```
select * from table where table.data.date1 > current_timestamp() and array_contains(table.data.values.primaryKey, \"10\")
```

Edit:

Array:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id        |values                                                                          |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|102|[[2025-05-11 20:00:00, [10]],[2022-07-05 20:00:00, [12]]] |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can youpost some sample data of the array please

Comment: and where is the array? please edit always your question with new information

Comment: I have added the complete array to the question @nbk Thanks!

Comment: How about applying `explode(data)` first to get each element in its own row, then the rest of the query becomes easier I think. See here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html

Comment: What result do you expect? you just need 2 columns? Array, but without some removed structs? Please add the expected output to the question.